# What is suggested size class to design iPhone app?

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

I have application which supports iPhone and iPad both in portrait and landscape mode, for that I used size class. In that I have requirement that in landscape some views are there and that will not in portrait. What happen with me that if I run app with selecting wCompact and hRegular and run app in landscape mode, it still takes views of portrait not landscape.
To solve this issue I always make sure that before running app my all view files are in wAny and hAny selected. Now I got new project which supports iPhone and portrait mode only. Now i think I should use `wAnyhAny` as this is standard , right? What is suggested or best way to start development with? So i do not face issue like this which i find before? Also can't figure out reason for happening this scenario, Any one can explain?

Comment: Xcode literally tells you which size classes are used on what devices in what orientations...

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry if I am misunderstanding this question.)

In landscape mode all current iPhones except 6+ are compact - compact. **In portrait mode they are width compact, height regular**.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines - Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

You can also choose to restrict an app to being portrait mode only in the general settings.

Comment: yes, You misunderstood my question, I know i can restrict app in portrait mode only, what my question is if I open xib file then which size class should be selected and recommended for app in portrait mode to select: wAnyhAny or wCompat hRegular

Comment: As above. iPhone (except iPhone 6+) is width compact, height regular in portrait mode. The Assistant editor preview will show how the constraints you set for each size class make it appear on difference devices.